# Google HTML service - Dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a form using the Google App Script platform, and I'm trying to add elements dynamically by pressing a button in the UI. 
how should I do it?
here is my code:

index.html

```
<form id="myForm">
   Name <input name="myName" type="text" /><br/><br/>
   Address <input name="myAddress" type="text" /><br/><br/>
   <input type="button" value="Add element" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addElement)" />
   <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).processForm(this.form)" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
 function addElement(){
   document.getElementById('myForm').append("input");

 }

 function showData(data){
   var div = document.getElementById('output');
   div.innerHTML = '<p>' + data + '</p>';
 }
</script>
```

here is Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return   HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function processForm(formObject){
  Logger.log(formObject);
  return formObject;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: no it doesn't work - it doesn't add a new textbox and it doesn't print the content of the textbox in the div ID="output" (it prints "[object Object]")

Comment: did you check the console? Do you see any error?

Comment: The console prints the output : {myAddress=test1, myName=test2} , but the new element doesn't appear in the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a Google server side function instead of the function in the Script tag:

```
<input type="button" value="Add element" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addElement)" />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="button" value="Add element" onclick="addElement()" />
```

I see that you are using `innerHTML`, so you know about that.

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

It looks like you are trying to use a method (append) that isn't available to the Element Object.  Maybe you are confusing the UI methods with DOM (Document Object Model).

[Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)

If you want to add an input tag, you could use something like this:

```
function addElement(){
  document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='inputTwo'>";
}
```

There is also an `appendChild` method:

[appendChild method - Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535934(v=vs.85).aspx)

There is also a `createElement` method:

[createElement Method - Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)

So, you can use the Document object, or the Element object.  Methods of the Document object are:

- document.createElement()
- document.removeChild()
- document.appendChild()
- document.replaceChild()